# protractor No element found using locator: By(xpath,

Tags: xpath

Actually I am testing in browser directly and I am getting error saying no element found using locator.

spec.js

```
 it('Test for Application Registration text', function () { 
     var ar = browser.findElement(by.xpath('/html/body/admin-app-root/layout/div[1]/cheader/nav/div/div[1]/a[2]'));
     expect(ar.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Application Registration'); 
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-bbu-25="" class="navbar-header"> 
 <a _ngcontent-bbu-25="" class="navbar-brand logo navbar-brand-logo" href="/register/core/feature-list"></a> 
 <a _ngcontent-bbu-25="" class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-title app-title ellipses" href="/register/core/feature-list">Application Registration</a>
</div>
```

Error:

```
Message:[chrome #01]     Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/adminapproot/layout/div[1]/
cheader/nav/div/div[1]/a[2]"}[chrome #01]       
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)[chrome #01]      
(Driver info:chromedriver=2.32.498550(9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),
 platfor=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)[chrome #01]   
 Stack:[chrome #01]   NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate 
 element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/admin-app-
 root/layout/div[1]/cheader/nav/div/div[1]/a[2]"}[chrome #01]       
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)[chrome #01]       
(Driver info:chromedriver=2.32.498550(9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),
 platfor=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)[chrome #01]        
 at WebDriverError(C:\\node_modules\proractor\node_modules\selenium-
 webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
```

Comment: No element found means exactly that there is no element for this xpath.

Comment: But their is link present on that path

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. There are evil developers that put bug into that library on purpose.
DOM might be different when you and your application check the document. Consider adding code of the page if that is your page or a link, if that is external page.

Comment: Read this nice article about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then do as it says - add at least Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: Do you want to click on link "Application Registration"?

Comment: No, this is the link but i am getting the link value i.e Application Registration and must equal to Application Registration. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine with this code:

```
it('Test for Application Registration text', function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var ar = element(by.xpath('/html/body/admin-app-root/layout/div[1]/c-header/nav/div/div[1]/a[2]'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ar));
        expect(ar.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Application Registration');
    });
```